# PHP detect Internet Explorer that is below version 10

Tags: php, internet-explorer, browser, detect

Could someone do this for me? As I only have macs and cannot test IE.

What's a good way of running an event IF the browser is Internet Explorer, and the version is under 10. So say it's IE 7, it will show the error, or if it's IE 9.9, it will show the error, however if it's IE 10, 10.1, 10.0.1 etc it will not show the error.

Comment: Googling `php detect browser` didn't turn up anything useful?

Comment: I'm aware of that, though I cannot test my code because I only owns macs. I was hoping someone could do that for me.

Comment: @DylanCross sign up for a free BrowserStack account and you can test it in any version of IE: http://www.browserstack.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function [get_browser()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) may be used for feature detection.

If you really want to only know the user's browser version you can look at the [$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

A word of caution: although most users won't do this, it is possible to send a different user agent string to the server which might be done to e.g. protect ones privacy. If someone wants to go as far as sending you a user agent to be able to use your website though they'll probably know how to deal with any bugs that may come up.

As a side question, what is the reason you're trying to limit your audience to IE 10 and up? Why not use a library such as [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) to fill in functions you might be missing in IE 9?

EDIT:
[Some info regarding the IE 10 user agent string](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/04/15/the-ie10-user-agent-string.aspx). You will want to read that so you know what to match your $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] against

Answer (score 2):

Come on, try to search next time ;-)
It's always recommended way of asking

[Can I detect IE6 with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/671890/492624)
[Detecting IE browser version using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3220344/492624)
[PHP get_browser: how to identify ie7 versus ie6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042176/php-get-browser-how-to-identify-ie7-versus-ie6)
[PHP: If internet explorer 6, 7, 8 , or 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302302/php-if-internet-explorer-6-7-8-or-9)

Comment: Next time, googlers can find this Stackoverflow thread though : )

Answer (score 1):

PHP's [get browser method](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) will return the user agent string. [All IE 10 browsers will contain MSIE 10.0 in this user agent.](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Internet%20Explorer/)